# Deeplinks gives empty path

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I have a problem of implementing DeepLinks. I can open the app from the URL like myapp://myapp.com/route. But it doesn’t handle path of it. It just opens the program.

I open it with :

```
 this.deeplinks.route({
  '/route': RoutePage
    }).subscribe(match => {
  // match.$route - the route we matched, which is the matched entry from the arguments to route()
  // match.$args - the args passed in the link
  // match.$link - the full link data
  console.log('Successfully matched route', match);
}, nomatch => {
  // nomatch.$link - the full link data
  console.error('Got a deeplink that didn\'t match', nomatch);
});
```

But im not receiving any console logs and the path is empty, just the following message :

[image]

My config.xml

```
 <plugin name="ionic-plugin-deeplinks" spec="^1.0.17">
    <variable name="URL_SCHEME" value="iskibris" />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_SCHEME" value="https" />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_HOST" value="iskibris.com" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_2_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_3_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_4_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_5_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_2_SCHEME" value="" />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_2_HOST" value="" />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_3_SCHEME" value="" />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_3_HOST" value="" />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_4_SCHEME" value="" />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_4_HOST" value="" />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_5_SCHEME" value="" />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_5_HOST" value="" />
</plugin>
```

Link of calling the app iskibris://iskibris.com/route
Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ionic Deeplinks` has two methods to open another page.

1. route
2. routeWithNavController

When using `route` method you should use nav.push to navigate another page. You can implement it in your `app.component.ts` as below.

```
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav:Nav;
  constructor(private deeplinks: Deeplinks) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {

       this.deeplinks.route({
         '/about': AboutPage
       }).subscribe(match => {
         this.nav.push(AboutPage);
       }, nomatch => {
         console.error('Got a deeplink that didn\'t match', nomatch);
      });

    });
  }
}
```

Or else use `routeWithNavController` that takes a reference to a `NavController` and handles the actual navigation. `routeWithNavController` method can be implemented as below inside your `app.component.ts`

```
      @ViewChild(Nav) nav:Nav;

      constructor(private deeplinks: Deeplinks) {

        platform.ready().then(() => {

         this.deeplinks.routeWithNavController(this.nav, {
            '/about': AboutPage

          }).subscribe(match => {

            console.log('Successfully matched route', JSON.stringify(match, null, 2));
          }, nomatch => {

            console.error('Got a deeplink that didn\'t match', nomatch);
          });
        });  
 }
```

And one thing,
In your config.xml ,
`<variable name="URL_SCHEME" value="iskibris" />` should be changed to
`<variable name="URL_SCHEME" value="myapp" />`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the only way that worked was, weirdly, by using the routeWithNavController method and passing an empty object on the second parameter. I'm on Ionic 3 and testing on an iPhone emulator, by the way.

Here are the tests:

```
/**
 * Using the routeWithNavController method and passing an empty object on the second parameter
 * WORKS!!
 * Did open the app and fired the "match" callback with the info of the clicked link
 */
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.deeplinks.routeWithNavController(this.nav, {
    // Nothing here. Empty object
  }).subscribe((match) => {
    alert('Match');
    alert(JSON.stringify(match));
  }, (nomatch) => {
    alert('No Match');
    alert(JSON.stringify(nomatch));
  });
});
```

the following examples **didn't** work.

```
/**
 * Using the routeWithNavController method and passing an object with a "what would be" route on the second parameter
 * DOESN`T WORK
 * Did open the app but didn't fire any of the callbacks. Neither "match" or "nomatch"
 */
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.deeplinks.routeWithNavController(this.nav, {
    '/': {}
  }).subscribe((match) => {
    alert('Match');
    alert(JSON.stringify(match));
  }, (nomatch) => {
    alert('No Match');
    alert(JSON.stringify(nomatch));
  });
});
```

```
/**
 * Using the route method and passing an object empty object
 * DOESN'T WORK (kinda)
 * Did open the app and fired the nomatch callback (after all, no route specified)
 */
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.deeplinks.route({
    // Nothing here. Empty object,
  }).subscribe((match) => {
    alert('Match');
    alert(JSON.stringify(match));
  },
  (nomatch) => {
    alert('No Match');
    alert(JSON.stringify(nomatch));
  });
});
```

```
/**
 * Using the route method and passing object with a "what would be" route on the second parameter
 * By the way, here I tried both links:
 * myapp://myapp.domain.com/
 * myapp://myapp.domain.com
 * DOESN`T WORK
 * Did open the app but didn't fire any of the callbacks. Neither "match" or "nomatch"
 */
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.deeplinks.route({
    '/': {},
  }).subscribe((match) => {
    alert('Match');
    alert(JSON.stringify(match));
  },
  (nomatch) => {
    alert('No Match');
    alert(JSON.stringify(nomatch));
  });
});
```

Because only the first one worked, I had to deal with the match object data and do the routing by myself, like this:

```
this.deeplinks.routeWithNavController(this.nav, {}).subscribe((match) => {
  if (match.$link.path == "/list") {
    this.nav.setRoot(ListPage);
  }
}, (nomatch) => {});
```

---

Here is the full code of my working app.component.ts with deeplinks:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';
import { Deeplinks } from '@ionic-native/deeplinks';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage: any = HomePage;

  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;

  constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen, public deeplinks: Deeplinks) {
    this.initializeApp();

    // used for an example of ngFor and navigation
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Home', component: HomePage },
      { title: 'List', component: ListPage }
    ];
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();

      this.deeplinks.routeWithNavController(this.nav, {}).subscribe((match) => {
        if (match.$link.path == "/list") {
          this.nav.setRoot(ListPage);
        }
      }, (nomatch) => {});
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }
}
```