# Angular - trying to use deeplinks but only the app is opening, routing not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I'm trying to use deeplinks but only the app is opening. The routing is not working.

Here is my code:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from ‘@angular/core’;
import { App, Platform, Nav, NavController } from ‘ionic-angular’;
import { StatusBar } from ‘@ionic-native/status-bar’;
import { SplashScreen } from ‘@ionic-native/splash-screen’;
import { Deeplinks } from ‘@ionic-native/deeplinks’;
import { HomePage } from ‘…/pages/home/home’;
import { HarryPage } from ‘…/pages/harry/harry’;

@Component({
    templateUrl: ‘app.html’
})

export class MyApp {
    @ViewChild(‘myNav’) nav: Nav;
    rootPage:any = HomePage;

    constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen,private deeplinks: Deeplinks) {
        platform.ready().then(() => {
            statusBar.styleDefault();
            splashScreen.hide();
        });
        this.deeplinks.routeWithNavController( this.nav, {
            ‘/harry’: HarryPage,
            ‘/’ :HomePage
        }).subscribe( (match)=>{
                console.log(match.$route);
                // alert(JSON.stringify(match))
            }, (noMatch)=>{
                // alert(JSON.stringify(noMatch));
            })
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to access the /harry route, only the home page is opening.

Comment: Seems like the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/q/51878423/2012013. If so, please, try take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68629374/2012013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its working if you put same code inside root-page, if you follow their documentations then nothing going to work.

Comment: Inside root page means app component or the initial page the component first routed to? I have the same issue..

Comment: Did you mean app.component.ts as root-page? I tried but still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try  `deeplinks` logic inside `platform.ready()` callback.

```
      @ViewChild(Nav) nav:Nav;

      constructor(private deeplinks: Deeplinks) {

        platform.ready().then(() => {

         this.deeplinks.routeWithNavController(this.nav, {
            '/harry': HarryPage,
            '/' : HomePage

          }).subscribe(match => {

            console.log('Successfully matched route', JSON.stringify(match, null, 2));
          }, nomatch => {

            console.error('Got a deeplink that didn\'t match', nomatch);
          });
        });  
 }
```

Comment: thanks for effort but already tried that thing,and its not working

Comment: Follow this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51880754/8850397  If no success update your question with your `config.xml`